# how to retrieve multiple selected value from asp:checkbox .net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

Does anyone know how can I retrieved the multiple selected value from asp:checkbox .net c#?

Example:
I'm new in .net c#, I have the following code, but I have no idea how can I retrieved the multiple selected value from .net c#

```
<tr>   
    <th class="graytext r">Add Test:</th>
    <td>
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="Test" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsTest" CssClass=""
            DataValueField="employeeid" DataTextField="fullname" 
            AppendDataBoundItems="false" >
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>  
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsTest" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SmartStaffConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="app_dsTest_select" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Are you looking for selected items or checked ones ??

Comment: @Akram Shahda This is the same for the CheckBoxList

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following:

```
for (int i=0; i<checkboxlist1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (checkboxlist1.Items[i].Selected)
    {
        Message.Text += checkboxlist1.Items[i].Text + "<br />";
    }
}
```

Refer to [CheckBoxList Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx).

Comment: Let's go functional: var rs = checkboxlist1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).Select(t=>t.Text).ToList(); and then you can concatenate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559415/concat-all-strings-inside-a-liststring-using-linq

Answer (score 4):

Propably the simplest approach is this:

```
foreach (ListItem item in myCheckboxList.Items)
{
  if (item.Selected)
  {
    // do something with this item
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread, but using .NET 4.5 (not sure if previous versions work), you can use LINQ to do this:

```
IEnumerable<ListItem> selectedItems = myCheckboxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected);
```

Answer (score 1):

try listitem.Selected property as i did below

```
protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = string.Empty;

    foreach (ListItem listitem in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {
        if (listitem.Selected)
            Label1.Text += listitem.Text + "<br />";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (ListItem item in myCheckboxList.Items)
{
  if (item.Selected)
  {
    //Your code goes here
  }
}
```

Comment: CheckboxList doesnt have a property `SelectedItems`, there is a property named `SelectedItem` (singular) but that just returns the first selected item.

Comment: @Bazz - But ListBox has so also CheckListBox. Check out this link, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.aspx

Comment: sorry to disappoint you but your reference is for winforms, OP is using asp.net http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You must iterate through the `Items`.

Refer to [CheckBoxList Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx#Introduction).

To determine which items are checked, iterate through the collection and test the `Selected` property of each item in the list.