# How to create one string from list of String?

Tags: c#, string, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Concat all strings inside a List<string> using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559415/concat-all-strings-inside-a-liststring-using-linq)

I am using C# 4.0, where I have a list non-null of string objects.

```
IList<String> Errors
```

What I want to do is to create a single string which has all list elements appended, one after another, with a new line character.

```
public String  ErrorMessage
{
    get { return Errors.SomeMethodHere(); }
}
```

One way I could think of is to loop on list of string. Is there any better way or in built System.String or LINQ method which I can use for this?

Comment: I think the best way is probably to loop through like you said

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559415/concat-all-strings-inside-a-liststring-using-linq

Comment: What's wrong with this question? Why 3 down votes?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the question. Probably, you wouldn't have asked it here since the solution is very simple.

Comment: This can be simple for someone, but I have never used this hence asked about that. Does simple solution mean down votes?

Comment: by that logic http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet should down vote every question he answers.

Comment: +1 to get the votes back to 0 :)

Comment: @Zaldy Baguinon There are no simple questions. The very fact that it is a question means that it needs an answer and hence has been asked. A question that you find difficult might be simple to others. raison d'etre for stackoverflow is not classifying questions easy or hard but to answer questions.

Comment: @P.K.: I thought that is the reason they down voted. I didn't down vote Maheeps question. I'm still new here perhaps some members think that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Errors.ToArray())` (for .NET 4 and up you don't need the ToArray)

More Info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx

Answer (score 5):

```
String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Errors.ToArray());
```

Comment: In .NET 4 you don't need the `ToArray`: [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx) has overloads that take `IEnumerable<String>` for the second parameter.

Comment: Not necessary to use `.ToArray()`, .Join method also allow IList<string> type data.

Comment: there are still some environments which use 3.5  (even 2.0 imagine!) --> no overload for IList

Answer (score 1):

```
public String ErrorMessage
{
    get 
    { 
        //Use your appropriate separator instead of ','
        return string.Join(",", Errors); 
        //return string.Join("", Errors); // Just concatenating all message 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Errors.Aggregate((left, right) => string.Format(@"{0}\n{1}", left, right));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string ErrorMessage(this IList<String> strList)
    {
        string retMessage = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < strList.Count; i++)
        {
            retMessage += strList[i].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        return retMessage;
    }

}
```

you can use the above code snippest to make an extended method to generate single string from list data.