# Iterating through a list with out using ForEach loop

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a list of list of strings:

```
var list = new List<string> {"apples","peaches", "mango"};
```

Is there a way to iterate through the list and display the items in a console window without using foreach loop may be by using lambdas and delegates.

I would like to the output to be like below each in a new line:

The folowing fruits are available: 
apples 
peaches 
mango

Comment: Why do you want to do this without `foreach`?

Comment: Heres an hint : retrieve the length and iterate from 0 to length -1

Comment: There are dozens of ways to do this. What are the requirements and why does `foreach` not satisfy them?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559415/concat-all-strings-inside-a-liststring-using-linq

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to concatenate all lines:

```
string lines = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list);
Console.Write(lines);
```

Answer (score 11):

By far the most obvious is the good old-fashioned `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("{0}", list[i]);
}
```

Comment: Ok, For me this is the clearest version and I like it the most. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
    Console.WriteLine(list[i])
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I love this particular aspect of linq

```
list.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

It's not using a ForEach loop per se as it uses the ForEach actor. But hey it's still an iteration.

Comment: Note that `List<T>.ForEach` is not a LINQ method, but just a plain old regular `List<T>` method; LINQ methods are never purely called for their side effects as `List<T>.ForEach` is.

Comment: Yeah technically I agree but these features are usually lumped together with linq :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`List<T>.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) method, which actually is not part of LINQ, but looks like it was:

```
list.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could try the following:

```
Debug.WriteLine("The folowing fruits are available:");
list.ForEach(f => Debug.WriteLine(f));
```

It's the very equivalent of a `foreach` loop, but not using the `foreach` keyword,

That being said, I don't know why you'd want to avoid a `foreach` loop when iterating over a list of objects.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to iterate a List:

```
//1 METHOD
foreach (var item in myList)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Id is {0}, and description is {1}", item.id, item.description);
}

//2 METHOD   
for (int i = 0; i<myList.Count; i++)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Id is {0}, and description is {1}", myList[i].id, myMoney[i].description);
}

//3 METHOD lamda style
myList.ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine("id is {0}, and description is {1}", item.id, item.description));
```

Comment: The brevity of method 3 is popular with some devs but it has the disadvantage that you cannot "break" -out of it, if processing can be curtailed before all items have been accessed.