# DataServiceCollection to a String

Tags: c#, wcf, xaml, wcf-data-services

I have dataServiceCollection and want to pull out some info from it and put it into a string.

```
    private DataServiceCollection<P.Groups> groups;
    public DataServiceCollection<P.Groups> Groups()
    {
        if (groups == null)
        {
            Uri pRoot = new Uri("http://localhost:19297/WcfDataService1.svc/");
            P.Entities data = new P.Entities(pRoot);

            var query = (DataServiceQuery<P.Groups>)data.GroupsSet;
            groups = new DataServiceCollection<P.Groups>();
            groups.LoadAsync(query);  
        }
        return groups;
    }


    protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
    {


        var g = Groups();
        this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"] = g;
    }
```

I can bind this to my xaml page with no problem, but I want to put "g" to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be just using linq, something like

```
g.Items.Aggregate((i, j) => i + delimeter + j)
```

from this post: [Concat all strings inside a List<string> using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559415/concat-all-strings-inside-a-liststring-using-linq)