# LINQ query EF error

Tags: linq-to-entities

I applied the soultion I found here to combine values of a returned list from an entity 
   into one string as this post guide : 
   [Concat all strings inside a List<string> using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559415/concat-all-strings-inside-a-liststring-using-linq)

But it gives error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Aggregate ....' and this method
cannot be translated into a store expression
```

How can I resolve this ...
Best regards

Comment: Have you added `using System.Linq` ?

Comment: I did ...I am getting the result back to telerik reporting.