# What is the Complexity of StringBuilder.ToString()

Tags: c#, big-o, stringbuilder

in C#, What is the Complexity of `StringBuilder.ToString()`? Is it O(1), O(N), or something else?

Comment: Look at the source and you'll know everything you need: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs#5a97da49a158a3c9

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek code is quite interesting for me according to straight C# codes. So Do you think it is O(N) because chunking?

Answer (score 2):

It varies between framework version; in older versions `StringBuilder` works on a `string` directly, so there is no additional cost in `.ToString()`: it just hands you the data directly (which can mean oversized, but it makes it work); so O(1).

In newer framework version, it uses a `char[]` backing buffer, so now when you `.ToString()` it will probably need to copy 2 x `Length` bytes, making it O(N).

Comment: Interesting. When did it change? Which versions use `string` directly?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I think 3.5 vs 4.0, but I'd need to check

Comment: What was the reason for that change?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek almost certainly ;p

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek It makes each `Append` faster, because it defers its work until the string is actually generated.  It also means that the memory doesn't need to be contiguous (until/unless) you generate an actual string, reducing the odds of the SB being on the LOH, fragmenting memory less, and being less vulnerable to OOM due to fragmented memory rather than simply insufficient memory.

Comment: @Servy appending to an oversized `string` is pretty much the same as appending to an oversized `char[]` - not much difference in terms of `Append`. Likewise, since the implementation is IIRC a `char[]`, it still has the same contiguous requirements

Comment: @MarcGravell You misunderstand the complexity of what SB does.  It is *not* just a wrapper for one big giant buffer.  It is, in effect, a linked list of char arrays, because each SB also has a reference to a "previous" string builder.  Basically when any given buffer runs out of space it doesn't make a new buffer and copy over the existing content (the pre 4.0 approach), it makes a new buffer *copies over none of the content*, and then holds onto a reference to the "previous" buffer.  `ToString` goes through the current, and all previous, buffers and appends them all to one big giant buffer.

Comment: Well according to your discussion, in the 'concatenation applications', the time I'd save by using Append with the StringBuilder will be wasted later when calling .ToString(). Even worse, ToString() creates a new instance which means allocating double the size in the memory (until the scope is done). So why would I use StringBuilder in the first place?

Comment: @yazanpro because it is a **lot** cheaper than creating lots of intermediate strings

Comment: You will be creating intermediate strings anyway. (StringBuilder.Append("test") VS string+="test") Both create the intermediate string "test"

Comment: @yazanpro now put it in a loop, and consider the unnecessary "footest", "footesttest" and "footesttesttest"