# Append quotes and comma to build in Clause for SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, regex

For handling support queries, i am trying to create a small interface that picks a newline delimited string of text from an ASP multiline textbox and gives the output with single quotes and comma adjusted to the text For Example

```
A1234
A1235
A1236
```

Would become something that can go into a 'SQL In Clause'

```
'A1234',
'A1235',
'A1236'
```

How can I improve the below code to achieve the same?

```
string[] arr = txtBox.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

I am aware of the excel formula (="'"&A1&"',") for the same but excel is not available on few machines.

Comment: Why not when the user enters the input, just force them to use a delimiter (such as ,) for separating the entries. Like how the USPS tracking tool work: https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction!input.action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were me I'd have:

```
var value = "IN ('" + String.Join("','", txtBox.Lines) + "')";
```

Or for the values only:

```
var value = "'" + String.Join("','", txtBox.Lines) + "'";
```

It's basically joining each line of the textbox (i.e. each value on each line) with `','` This is fine, but you then to ensure there is a `'` at the start and end.

Further reading on the `Lines` property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx

## EDIT:

```
string[] lines = txt.Split(new Char[] { '\n', '\r' },
                            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var value = "'" + String.Join("','", lines) + "'";
```

Comment: I tried the txtBox.Lines property. My interface is a web interface and i am not able to do the same for an asp textbox. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this answer... [Concat all strings inside a List<string> using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559415/concat-all-strings-inside-a-liststring-using-linq)

...there's an Agregate() function! never knew that... so you can say

```
        var txtBoxText = @"A1234
A1235

A1236";
        var result = txtBoxText.Split(
            Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(),
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(x=>"'" + x + "'")
            .Aggregate((i,j)=> i + "," + j);

        Assert.AreEqual(result, @"'A1234','A1235','A1236'");
```