# Returning a files name as string

Tags: c#, string, linq, contains, fileinfo

I have a List< FileInfo > fileList and I am trying to make a variable containing the File name like the code below:

```
var newFileName = fileList.Select(x => x.Name).ToString();
```

Now I would expect the value of newFileName to be the files name but the value I get is this:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[System.IO.FileInfo,System.String]
```

I need to get the file name as a string becouse I want to check if another List< string > filesTemp already contains the newFileName.

```
if (!filesTemp.Contains(newFileName))
```

Why is the value as I mentioned and how can i get the actual Name of the file?

Thanks for any help

Comment: please show the fileList declaration

Comment: What `Type` of items are in `fileList`? Strings? FileInfo's?

Comment: oh sorry I have edited it

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx use .name

Comment: @Simon: What `Type` of items are in `filesTemp`? `Strings`? `FileInfo`'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select` returns a lazily evaluated collection, you need to use `FirstOrDefault` to get the first value from the collection.

```
var newFileName = fileList.Select( x => x.Name ).FirstOrDefault();
```

But that only works for a single file name, you can use the `Any` method in the if statement instead to check whether or not any of the names from `fileList` are present in `filesTemp`.

```
var isInTemp = fileList.Any( x => filesTemp.Contains( x.Name ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

We will get the name of the file from the property `FileInfo.Name`

As youhave  not determined any files in select, You can get file name like following way.

```
fileList[0].Name
```

If you want to select file according to name,

```
fileList.Select(x => x.Name == name).ToList(); // Select file according to specific name.
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
var newFileName = fileList.Select(x => x.Name).ToString();
```

by

```
IList<string> newFileName = fileList.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

It will return a list of file names, then do your comparison

Answer (score -1):

Seems like your problem is about aggregating.

I think the link below should be what you're looking for:
[Concat all strings inside a List<string> using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559415/concat-all-strings-inside-a-liststring-using-linq)