# How to exclude character appending if last element of ArrayList

Tags: java, c#, for-loop, arraylist

I am attempting to build a string using a `for()` loop to iterate over the elements of an `ArrayList`. I want to append a coma after each element of the ArrayList is appended on to the String that I'm building, but I don't want to append the coma after the last element of the ArrayList has been appended.

This is what I've attempted so far, but a coma is still added in after the last element.

```
public String buildWOEIDQuery(ArrayList searchCriteria)
{
    String query = "http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/places.q('";
    for (int i = 0; i < searchCriteria.Count; i++ )
    {
        if(searchCriteria.)

        query += (String)searchCriteria[0];
        if(i != searchCriteria.Count)
        {
            query += ",";
        }
    }
    query += "')?appid=" + devKey;

    return query;
}
```

The query should end up looking like this if, for example there are 3 search criteria:

`http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/places.q('criteria1,criteria2,criteria3')?appid=dj0yJmk9Tm`

If `i` is equal to the Count of the ArrayList, doesn't that make it the last element of the list, thus should no append a coma?

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList` anymore. It belongs old days when C# doesn't have generics. Use `List<T>` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem 1 :** your condition `if(i != searchCriteria.Count)` willbe  never true because your for loop will not come inside if `i` equals the `ArrayList.Count`.

so you need to have the condiftion `if(i != searchCriteria.Count)` to skip the comma for last item.

You can also use `TrimEnd()` function to remove the last comma.

Try This:

```
query = query.TrimEnd(',');
```

**Problem 2:** in your loop you are hardcoding value zero to get first element from `ArrayList` always

Replace This:

```
query += (String)searchCriteria[0];
```

With This:

```
query += (String)searchCriteria[i];
```

**Suggestion 1:** don't use `ArrayList` as it is legacy you can use Generic `List<T>`.

Complete Code:

```
public String buildWOEIDQuery(List<string> searchCriteria)
{
    String query = "http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/places.q('";
    for (int i = 0; i < searchCriteria.Count; i++ )
    {
       query += searchCriteria[i] + ",";        
    }
    query = query.TrimEnd(',');
    query += "')?appid=" + devKey;

    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your check does not work is that `i` is equal to searchCriteria.Count-1 in the last iteration of the loop. So you could modify your if check to be `i != searchCriteria.Count-1`

As an alternative, you could bypass the check and use the `TrimEnd` function to trim off the excess characters after the loop.

```
var query = "a,b,c,";
query = query.TrimEnd(',');
MessageBox.Show(query);    // a,b,c
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `ArrayList`; use `List<string>` or even better `IEnumerable<string>` instead. Your code can be more elegant if you use `string.Join()`. It is tailor-made for requirements like yours. The complete solution is as under:

```
public string buildWOEIDQuery(IEnumerable<string> searchCriteria)
{
    string query = "http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/places.q('";
    query += string.Join(",", searchCriteria);
    query += "')?appid=" + devKey;

    return query;
}
```

You can look at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/559415/1797393) on SO.