# Search in the list and get all related data c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, oop

I have list and I need to search for specific item and get related data from this list.

```
 public People(string name, string talent)
        {
            Name= name;
            Talent= talent;
        }
        public string Name;
        public int Talent;
```

I added many items to that list

```
List<People> peopleList = new List<People>();
For example;
"John","magic",
"John","windpower",
"John","electricpower",
"John","firepower",
"Luigi","storm",
"Luigi","fire",
```

I'm trying to get people all talents like;

```
string talentsofJohn = "magic,windpower,electricpower,firepower";
string talentsofLuigi = "storm,fire";
```

I have tried many ways especially Linq but couldnt make it;

```
var talentsofJohn = peopleList.Find(item => item.name == "John");
```

Comment: People is plural; your class would be better named "Person"

Comment: CaiusJard sorry for my english this is my best :) @ThrowingSpoon yes names are unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, you're just not thinking in "collection of items" mode

```
var talentsofJohn = peopleList.Find(item => item.name == "John");
```

Only gets you a single `People` object because `Find` stops as soon as the first match is found

You want to get a *collection* of all matching items, and you want to find by the `item.Name == "John"` - note that I've changed the capitalisation of your `name` to `Name` because that's the name of the publicly visible property.

For this, you can use LINQ `.Where` - the result of this Where is an enumerable collection of `People` objects. From that, you want to LINQ `Select` just the `Talent` property from each person (the select will give you an enumerable collection of talent strings):

```
var talentsofJohn = peopleList.Where(p => p.Name == "John").Select(q => q.Talent);
```

If you want them all in a string, separated by commas:

```
var str = string.Join(",", talentsOfJohn);
```

Note, you can avoid the use of string.Join, and do it all in LINQ using the Aggregate method, but there are a few good reasons why you might not want to do so. For more info including arguments as to why, see [Concat all strings inside a List<string> using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559415/concat-all-strings-inside-a-liststring-using-linq)

A final note.. `List.Find` isn't LINQ.. It's just a plain old method on `List`. As a result, if you do put this LINQ code into your app and it says something like:

> List does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method accepting a first argument of blahblah was found, are you missing an assembly reference?

You need to ensure your class file has at the top:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: You are my Thor, you are the creator of happiness.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a combination of `Where` (to filter the list) and `Select` (to pick out an individual property) :

```
var talents = peopleList.Where(p => p.Name == "John").Select(p => p.Talent);
```

If you then want it in a comma separated string you can use `string.Join` on the returned enumeration

```
var asString = string.Join(",", talents)
```

Comment: Absolutely Zeus or fire creator. I just don't know

Answer (score 0):

Your `Talent` type is **int**, change it to **string** or it would not work as you want.

Then try this to retrive talents for specific person:

```
string userName = "John";
var talentsOfPerson = peopleList
                        .Where(person => person.Name == userName)
                        .Select(person => person.Talent)
                        .ToList();
```

Also the proper name for your class should be `Person` not People

Comment: You are my Thor too, you are the creator of happiness too :)

Answer (score 0):

First, let's use `Where` to filter your list down to just people named *John*.

```
var johnList = peopleList.Where(item => item.name == "John");
```

Next, let's use `Select` to only extract the people's talents:

```
var talentList = johnList.Select(item => item.talent);
```

Finally, you can use `string.Join` to convert an array or list to a string:

```
string talents = string.Join(",", talentList);
```

LINQ allows you to chain these together, so you can do it all in a single line:

```
string talents = string.Join(
    ",", 
    peopleList
        .Where(item => item.name == "John")
        .Select(item => item.talent)
    );
```

Comment: I have some suspicious about you have some power.

Answer (score 0):

Use loop of your choice like it could be for loop,for each loop , while loop.. etc

```
foreach(people p in peoplelist)
{ 
  if(p.name=="john")
   {

    Console.WriteLine(p.name + " " + p.talent)

   }
}
```

**OR**

```
for(int i=0;i<peoplelist.Count;i++)
{
     if(peoplelist[i].name=="john")
       {

        Console.WriteLine(peoplelist[i].name + " " + peoplelist[i].talent)

       }
}
```

hope this will help you

Comment: You are my Thor too, you are the creator of happiness too :)