# How to concatenate a list of strings together, with a comma between each value?

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq

I need help with this code. I want to split words in foreach loop like this but I don't want a `,` after the last word. Any suggestions?

```
var listOtherWords = (from o in Words
                      where !o.ToUpper().StartsWith("A")
                      where !o.ToUpper().StartsWith("B")
                      where !o.ToUpper().StartsWith("C")
                      select o).ToList();

Console.WriteLine();
Console.Write("Other Words: ");

foreach (string o in lisOtherWords)
{
    Console.Write(o + " ,");
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concat all strings inside a List<string> using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559415/concat-all-strings-inside-a-liststring-using-linq)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use [`String.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7.2) method:

```
Console.Write(string.Join(" ,", listOtherWords));
```

Or use `\b \b"`:

```
foreach (string o in listOtherWords)
{
    Console.Write(o + " ,");
}

Console.Write("\b \b");
```

It moves the caret back, then writes a whitespace character that overwrites the last character and moves the caret forward again.

Answer (score 1):

you would be better off using `string.Join`:

```
Console.Write(string.Join(" ,", lisOtherWords));
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than `Join` You can also use `Aggregate` method:

```
string line = listOtherWords.Aggregate((a,b) => $"{a} ,{b}");
```

The only difference is that you will be able to add additional logic to your loop. e.g:

```
string line = listOtherWords.Aggregate((a,b) =>
{
    if(...) ...
    return $"{a} ,{b}";
});
```